# Overloading comparison operators to work with STL sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, operator-overloading, stl-algorithm

I am writing a program that will read in a list of names with social security numbers (not real ones of course) and sort the list based on either last name or ssn, depending on a command line argument. I have overloaded the < operator and also overloaded input and output operators for simplicity. Everything compiles fine until I add the sort function and the output at the end of main. I'm stumped. Any ideas? Any other tips are also greatly appreciated.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

enum sortVar { NAME, SOCSEC };

class record {
    public:
        friend bool operator<(record& rhs, record& name);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, record& toWrite);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, record& toRead);
        bool t_sort;    
    private:
        string firstName, lastName, ssn;

};

bool operator<(record& rhs, record& next)
{
    if (rhs.t_sort = false) {
        if (rhs.lastName == next.lastName)
            return rhs.firstName < next.firstName;
        else
            return rhs.lastName < next.lastName;
    }
    else if (rhs.t_sort = true)
        return rhs.ssn < next.ssn;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, record& toWrite)
{
    out << toWrite.lastName 
         << " " 
         << toWrite.firstName 
         << "    " 
         << toWrite.ssn;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, record& toRead)
{
    in >> toRead.lastName >> toRead.firstName >> toRead.ssn;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc !=3) {
        cerr << "Incorrect number of arguments.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (argv[1] != "name" || argv[1] != "socsec") {
        cerr << "Argument 1 must be either 'name' or 'socsec'.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    sortVar sortMode;
    if (argv[1] == "name")
        sortMode = NAME;
    else if (argv[1] == "socsec")
        sortMode = SOCSEC;

    ifstream fin(argv[2]);

    vector<record> nameList;
    while(!fin.eof()) {
        record r;
        if (sortMode == NAME)
            r.t_sort = false;
        else if (sortMode == SOCSEC)
            r.t_sort = true;
        fin >> r;
        nameList.push_back(r);
    }

    //sort(nameList.begin(), nameList.end());
    //cout << nameList;

}
```

Comment: First problem: using `=` where you want `==`. Didn't your compiler give you a nasty warning?

Comment: Generally it's helpful to list the compiler you're using and the exact error message you get.

Comment: Learn about being const correct. There is no need for most of your parameters to be references to non-const

Comment: You should start using `const` a bit more in your code... the comparisons and insertion operator (`operator>>`) should take the `record` argument by constant reference (they should not change the object they receive).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of strange, and something your compiler should warn about

```
if (rhs.t_sort = false)
```

You are not testing the value of `t_sort` but always *setting* it to false.

Testing  a `bool` against `true` or `false` is bit unnecessary anyway, as this is what the `if`-statement is doing already.

Try this code instead

```
bool operator<(const record& rhs, const record& next)
{
    if (rhs.t_sort) {
        return rhs.ssn < next.ssn;
    }
    else
    {
        if (rhs.lastName == next.lastName)
            return rhs.firstName < next.firstName;
        else
            return rhs.lastName < next.lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I fixed that and I also noticed that I was attempting to output a vector rather than a record. I'm still getting an error when I try to use the sort algorithm though. I think I'm either calling the function incorrectly or there's an error in my operator<() function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that having an ordering for your `record` class has a real meaning, not only for arbitrary sorting purposes? Consider a class for large integers, where a such an ordering for your objects makes sense, but would it make such valid sense for your records? Or does it lose its meaning if you never sort?

[imo] Do not couple this ordering introduced by `operator<` with your class definition unless it has a real correspondence with it, in other words, if it is intuitively clear for human beings that some "object a" is smaller than some "object b".

This holds especially true if you ever want to have different orderings for non intuitively order-able class objects, think of ascending vs. descendening, by first name, by last name, by number of cars, et cetera. Then nobody will remember what your default ordering is without looking up the documentation/code, thus loosing even its convenience.

Instead, either pass functors or in-place lambda function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    int x;
    Foo (int x) : x(x) {}
};

struct FooAscending : std::binary_function<Foo,Foo, bool>
{
    bool operator() (Foo const &lhs, Foo const &rhs) const { 
        return lhs.x < rhs.x;
    }
};

int main () {
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    foos.emplace_back(1);
    foos.emplace_back(2);

    sort (foos.begin(), foos.end(), 
          [](Foo const &l, Foo const &r) { return l.x < r.x; });
    sort (foos.begin(), foos.end(), 
          [](Foo const &l, Foo const &r) { return l.x > r.x; });

    sort (foos.begin(), foos.end(), FooAscending());
}
```