# sorting a structure in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, structure

i want to sort an array using structure (my first time using structure).this structure gets FirstName and ID number of some students and the problem is that instead showing the FirstName  it shows other FirstNames (I use dev C++)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
  long long int ID;
  string FirstName,LastName;
} mystudent[100];
void PrintInformation(Student sEmployee[100],int b)
{
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
            cout << "First Name:   " << sEmployee[i].FirstName<< endl;
            cout << "ID:  " << sEmployee[i].ID<< endl;
            }
}
void Sort (Student mine);
int main ()
{
   int n, c, d, temp;
   cout << "Enter element: ";
   cin>>n;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
   {
    cout << "Enter FirstName "<<i+1<<": ";
    cin>>mystudent[i].FirstName;
   } 
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
   {
    cout << "Enter ID "<<mystudent[i].FirstName<<": ";
    cin>>mystudent[i].ID;
   }
  for (int i = 1 ; i <= n - 1; i++) 
  {
    d = i;
    while ( d > 0 && mystudent[i].ID < mystudent[i-1].ID)
     {
      temp         = mystudent[i].ID;
      mystudent[i].ID   = mystudent[i-1].ID;
      mystudent[i-1].ID = temp;
      mystudent[i-1].FirstName=mystudent[i].FirstName;
      d--;
    }
  }
  cout<<"Sorted list in ascending order:\n";

  PrintInformation(mystudent,n); 
   getch();
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If this is for actual production code, I would recommend [using std::sort on your array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669900/using-sort-in-stl-to-sort-an-array) and [providing a strict less than operator for your Student class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336579/overloading-comparison-operators-to-work-with-stl-sort-in-c) - also a custom operator function in place of the less-than operator may make sense, too.

Comment: i used the code below **woolstar** to swap the Firstnames but now it doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: thanks everybody my problem has solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
  temp         = mystudent[i].ID;
  mystudent[i].ID   = mystudent[i-1].ID;
  mystudent[i-1].ID = temp;
  mystudent[i-1].FirstName=mystudent[i].FirstName;
```

swaps the `ID`, but copies the `FirstName`.  Even worse, it doesn't do anything with `LastName`.

Try instead:

```
struct Student tempstudent = mystudent[i] ;
mystudent[i]= mystudent[i-1] ;
mystudent[i-1]= tempstudent ;
```

Or better yet, use the STL.

```
#include <utility>

std::swap(mystudent[i], mystudent[i-1]) ;
```

Note, `swap` is in `<algorithm>` if you're pre C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Provide an `operator<` and use `std::sort`, and rely on the default copy constructor doing the right thing. If you need to sort in more than one way, you can provide a comparator object to the sort algorithm instead of providing `operator<`.

```
...

struct Student {
  long long int ID;
  string FirstName,LastName;
} mystudent[100];

bool operator<(const Student& s1, const Student& s2) {
  return s1.ID < s2.ID;
}

...

int main () {
  ...
  std::sort(mystudent,mystudent+100)
  cout<<"Sorted list in ascending order:\n";
  PrintInformation(mystudent,n); 
  getch();
  return 0; 
}
```

If your compiler supports C++11 you could alternately use an inline lambda expression for the sort, and omit the `operator<`.

```
...

struct Student {
  long long int ID;
  string FirstName,LastName;
} mystudent[100];

...

int main ()
{
  ...
  std::sort(mystudent, mystudent+100,
     [](mystudent const & a, mystudent const &b){return a.ID < b.ID;});

  cout<<"Sorted list in ascending order:\n";    
  PrintInformation(mystudent,n); 
  getch();
  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is swapping just the `ID` field of the structure. You are assigning (copying) `FirstName` field and dont do anything with `LastName`.`struct`s can be directly assigned to each other using the `=` operator :

```
struct Student temp = mystudent[i] ;
mystudent[i]= mystudent[i-1] ;
mystudent[i-1]= temp ;
```

Comment: Seriously?  If you're going to copy my answer, at least type it again instead of copy and paste.